# Sizeof vs Strlen

Tags: c, sizeof, strlen

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char string[] = "october"; // 7 letters

    strcpy(string, "september"); // 9 letters

    printf("the size of %s is %d and the length is %d\n\n", string,
        sizeof(string), strlen(string));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ ./a.out
the size of september is 8 and the length is 9
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax or what?

Comment: You are writing past the end of the array `string`. This is undefined behavior. `string` can only hold 8 characters (7 for "october" and 1 for the null terminator). When you call `strcpy`, you are writing 10 characters to it (9 for "september" and 1 for the null terminator), which means you have gone past the end of the array and are overwriting the adjacent memory.

Comment: Note that `sizeof` is calculated at *compile* time where as `strlen` is run time.

Comment: @Naveen: Be aware that that is not necessarily true where VLAs are involved.

Comment: @caf: Maybe I'm gonna feel clueless but..... What do you mean by VLAs? Very large arrays? lol

Comment: @CoryGross: A "variable length array", an array type where the length is not an integer constant expression (or the element type is itself a variable length array type).

Comment: @caf: So your saying `sizeof` can be used on a dynamically allocated array and in this context will not be calculated at compile time?

Comment: I am saying that in the function `int foo(int n) { int a[n];` the value `sizeof a` is not calculated at compile-time.

Answer (score 43):

`sizeof` and `strlen()` do different things.  In this case, your declaration

```
char string[] = "october";
```

is the same as

```
char string[8] = "october";
```

so the compiler can tell that the size of `string` is 8.  It does this at compilation time.

However, `strlen()` counts the number of characters in the string at run time.  So, after you call `strcpy()`, `string` now contains "september".  `strlen()` counts the characters and finds 9 of them.  Note that you have not allocated enough space for `string` to hold "september".  This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, even after copying "September", its still giving correct length of string despite we don't know the 9th position contains null character or not!

Answer (score 1):

The Output is correct because

first statement string size was allocated by compiler that is 7+1 (October is 7 bytes & 1 byte for null terminator at compile time)

Second statement: you are copying September (9 bytes to 8 bytes string);

there for you got size of September as 8 bytes (still `strlen()` will not work for September it does not have null character)

Comment: The string literal `"september"` implicitly contains the null character, so `strlen()` will work, if the program hasn't crashed already (due to writing past the end of the `string` array)

Comment: @TimothyJones: It's undefined behavior, so technically, there are options besides "crash" or "work". Never discount the possibility of nasal demons.

Answer (score 0):

Your destination array is 8 bytes (length of "october" plus \0) and you want to put in 9 chars in that array.

`man strcpy` says:
If the destination string of a strcpy() is not large enough, then anything might happen.

Please tell me what you really want to do, because this smells bad long way

Comment: This is the test program for understanding the working of sizeof()