# Is it possible to get the number of elements currently stored in an array in C?

Tags: c

I know it's possible to use the sizeof function to get the size, but it doesn't get a true count of the array length. If I set an array of int 50 and I stored only 10 numbers in there, I would want to get 10 as the number of elements, but of course that won't happen. I know this is definitely a trivial question, but bear with me here and help me on this if it is possible.

My code so far takes an entire sentence and stores it in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char array[50]={0};
    fgets(array, 50, stdin);
    int len = sizeof(array);  // it doesn't work :((((((
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
```

}

As you guys can see, if the user decides to only enter a word of lets say "Bobby Foo" then I would want len number of 9 including the space, but the sizeof function only gets length of the size of the array declared which is 50.. >.>..

Comment: Sadly, C arrays are just low level blobs of memory. Its the responsibility of the programmer to keep track (using a separate variable) of how many elements are stored in the array and in what positions of the array they are stored in.

Comment: How about a function that searches the array for the newline character?

Comment: You may find this question informative: [**"sizeof-vs-strlen"**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937181/sizeof-vs-strlen)

Comment: The only way I know how to go through an array(search) is with a for loop, and that would mean I need to know what n (length is). I know there's other ways, but I am still a noob at this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Comment: Strictly, the size of your array is 50, because arrays do not have 'not-set' value -- any bit pattern is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strlen` to get the size of the `array`. You need to include `string.h`.

`sizeof()` is not a function it is an operator. When `sizeof` is applied to the name of a static array (not allocated through `malloc`), the result is the size in bytes of the whole array.

If you are using `fgets`, then you need to remove `\n` from the string. A simple way would be:

```
array[strlen(array) - 1] = '\0';
```

A quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char array[50]={0};
    char *p;
    fgets(array, 50, stdin);
    //Remove `\n` from the array.
    if ((p=strchr(array, '\n')) != NULL)
        *p = '\0';
    size_t len = strlen(array);  // Use strlen to find the length of string
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait are you serious :D? I was under the assumption we needed some sort of actual code algorithm. So this would ONLY count the number of elements stored inside including the space?

Comment: @user3718584 `strlen()` will count the number of `char`s in the array up until the first non-NULL character.

Comment: @user3718584 As long as the char array is NUL terminated

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by NUL terminated, but it does always end in a newline as well when I press enter. I would assume the newline char would also be counted.

Comment: Yup, I just did that after finding out from you guys that I have to use a '\0' to get rid of the newline, before I was going to set it to 0 lol..

Comment: Probably should check for '\n' before removing it and not use strlen twice.

Comment: `strlen(array) - 1` mostly is way into desaster. Using the `strchr()` approach is the way to go. Also note that `fgets()` does not append the `\n` in any case. @user3718584

Comment: `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`, same for `sizeof`.

Comment: @alk: Thanks, by reading your suggestion I read more about `size_t`. Could you please explain why `strlen(array) - 1` is disaster? Also I'm unclear regarding your statement that _`fgets()` does not append the `\n` in any case_. Reason why I'm asking is when we accept input using `fgets()`, I see `\n` in the end.

Comment: @1336087: 1.: `strlen(array) - 1`: Imagine what would happen if you'd pass in `""` to `strlen() - 1`? 2.: If `fgets()` encounters `EOF` before a `\n`, it would not append a `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Is it possible to get the number of elements currently stored in an array in C?

1. Short answer: No.  You need to track this information yourself.
2. You happen to be using [fgets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) with a character array.  Since in this case you're getting a C "string", you can use the C function [strlen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen).
3. It's worth noting that fgets() will also return a newline - so your string might be a one (Mac, Linux) or two (DOS/Windows) characters longer than you expect.

PS:

Here is a bit more about C strings, including the concept of "null termination" (if you're not already familiar with them):

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html

Comment: yes you are correct, it does have a newline and when I printf it gives me these 2 blank spaces. I am assuming I can just delete this new line later on.

Comment: Ad 3) `fgets` is most often used to read from _text streams_ (like `stdin`), so new-line (whatever it happens to be on some system) is converted to `'\n'`.