# Valgrind Use of unitialized value of size 8

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I recently ran a full leak check with valgrind only to discover this error and "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" it has been throwing. What am i doing wrong here? It keeps pointing to this function:

```
int tldlist_add(TLDList *tld, char *hostname, Date *d) {

    if (date_compare(tld->begin, d) > 0 || date_compare(tld->end, d) < 0)
        return 0;

    char *dot = strrchr(hostname, '.') + 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < sizeof(dot))
    {
        dot[i] = tolower(dot[i]);
        i++;
    }
    char *temptld = (char *)malloc(sizeof(dot));
    strcpy(temptld, dot);

    tld->root = addnode(tld, temptld, tld->root);
    tld->count++;
    return 1;

}
```

specifically at this line: `dot[i] = tolower(dot[i]);`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What's up with all the pointless casting? You could remove all casts from that function and it would be all the better for it. Only cast if necessary, otherwise you can hide potential problems.

Comment: If you have a different question, please post it as a new question.  Don't completely change the existing question, which invalidates the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(dot)` gives size of pointer not sizeof string pointed to by pointer `dot` and `dot[i]` will lead to out of bound memory access.

Comment: `sizeof(string)`? You mean `strlen(dot)`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're using [`sizeof` where you should use `strlen`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9937181/3425536).
2. You're needlessly casting an `int` to `int`, twice.
3. You're casting the result of `malloc`. [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3425536).
4. You forgot to allocate enough memory for the null terminator.