# Not showing only few chars when connecting strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have simple function that should connect string but in different way.
If i have one string "abc" and another "123" final string should be "a1b2c3".

Here is code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *connStrings(char *s1, char *s2) {
    int s1L, s2L,i = 0,k=1,j=0;
    s1L = sizeof(s1);
    s2L = sizeof(s2);

    char* result = (char*) malloc((s1L + s2L));
    while (s1[i] != '\0') {
        result[j] = s1[i++];
        j = j + 2;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (s2[i] != '\0') {
        result[k] = s2[i++];
        k = k + 2;
    }
    result[s1L + s2L] = '\0';
    printf("\n %s \n", result);
}

int main() {
    connStrings("abcdefghi","123456789");
}
```

So what's the problem?
the final output of this program is still the same "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8"
It ignores i and 9 somehow. Even if I add more chars into both strings it still prints the same
 "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8". I will be thankful for any help or advice.

Comment: `sizeof(s1)` is not the length of the string `s1`. Did you meant `strlen(s1)` ?

Comment: This will return size of pointer, not the string length: `sizeof(s1)`

Comment: Ou yes that was the mistake. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Your function type is `char *` but you aren't returning anything

Comment: This answers your question: [Sizeof vs Strlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937181/sizeof-vs-strlen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper function return type and `strlen` instead of `sizeof`

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void connStrings(char *s1, char *s2) {
    int s1L, s2L, i = 0, k = 1, j = 0;
    s1L = strlen(s1);
    s2L = strlen(s2);

    char *result = (char *) malloc((s1L + s2L + 1 )); // extra one for the `null` terminator `\0`
    while (s1[i] != '\0') {
        result[j] = s1[i++];
        j = j + 2;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (s2[i] != '\0') {
        result[k] = s2[i++];
        k = k + 2;
    }
    result[s1L + s2L + 1] = '\0';
    printf("\n %s \n", result);
    // free memory when you're done
    free(result);

}

int main() {
    connStrings("abcdefghi", "123456789");
    return 0; // or use void
}
```

Comment: should add 1 to the malloc as well.

Comment: And here `result[s1L + s2L] = '\0';` should not be +1 too?

Comment: I am asking because when  i add + 1 it adds "=" at the end of the string and i get error "heap corruption detected". (when i ctrc and ctrlv your code i get error) But i understand that my main problem was in strlen so i mark this as solved) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array as an argument to a function, what you're really passing is a pointer to the first element of the array.

`sizeof` will not return the length of the buffer in this case, but the size of a pointer.

Fortunately, C strings have the useful property of being terminated with a null character (`'\0'`), which allows functions like `strlen` to give you the actual length of the string, even when all you have is a pointer and not the array. `strlen` works similar to this:

```
size_t strlen(char *s)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    while(*s) ret++, s++;
    return ret;
}
```

Even when calculating the length of a string when you have an actual array, you still shouldn't use `sizeof` because that will return the entire size of the buffer, which may not be the length of the string within it.

Consider:  `char s[100] = "Hello World";`

`sizeof s` would be 100; `strlen(s)` would return 11.